# Z3 constants and python 'in' operator

Tags: z3, z3py

I was wondering if it is safe to use membership testing with python built-in set type and z3 constants.

Suppose to have the following example:

```
a = Int('a')
a2 = Int('a')

s = set()
s.add(a)

print(a2 in s)
```

The last line return `True`, which is my desired behaviour (when `name` is the same). However, the `__eq__()` operator in ExpRef is redefined to return the constraint `'self == other'` and so I don't understand where this `True` come from. Could it happen that the `in` operator might return `True` when having two constants with a different `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__eq__` indeed just returns a constraint, but `__bool__` on that constraint returns a boolean that compares whether the two arguments are syntactically equal. So basically `__eq__` is overloaded in such a way that `a == a2` by itself just creates an equality constraint, but using it in a boolean context actually makes it compare whether `a` and `a2` are syntactically the same. So two constants with the same name will compare equal, but constants with different names would not.

`__hash__` is also defined using that same notion of equality. So it's safe to use in sets (or as keys in dicts).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is safe to do so. It works because you are literally comparing the underlying representation of these objects (as ASTs), and they'll never be equal in this sense if you have different names.

But I have to say this is rather unorthodox. To illustrate, consider this:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
solver = Solver()
solver.add(a == b)

s = set()
s.add(a)
s.add(b)

print(s)
```

this will print `{b, a}` even though we manifestly asserted that `a` and `b` are exactly the same to the solver. This could lead to confusion down the road.

Of course, this could very well be exactly what you are trying to do. That is, tell apart the variables syntactically, regardless of their value. I can see some use cases for this if you are doing "meta" level z3 programming, i.e., building libraries on top of it, but in general, you should avoid doing anything that inspects the identity of objects like this in z3py. It can get really confusing if you start conflating object-identity and value-identity. One typically wants value-identity in symbolic programming, but again, it depends on your use case.